# Error retrieving data from Cloud Firestore database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I sent a `Map<String, LatLng>` to my Cloud Firestore database. Now, I want to retrieve the data as a Map. Then, I want to send that Map to my fragment so that the fragment can plot the LatLng on a google map.

Here's what I've done:

I successfully retrieved the data from the database, but the error comes in the fragment, where I want to get the LatLng from the Map.

How I retrieve the data:
MapsActivity:

```
Source source = Source.DEFAULT;

pinColRef.get(source)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                       ArrayList arrayOfPins = new ArrayList<java.util.Map>();
                       arrayOfPins.add(document.getData());
                       Log.i(TAG, document.getData().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

As you see, I retrieve the data and then use getData() to get the Map I sent. The Log.i statement successfully shows the data from the database as a Map.

So, I send that data to the fragment.

Here's how I did that:

MapsActivity:

```
public ArrayList getPinData() {
    return arrayOfPins;
}
```

Fragment:

```
MapsActivity activity = (MapsActivity) getActivity();
ArrayList arrayOfPins = activity.getPinData();
```

How I try to plot the LatLng from the database (in the MapReadyCallback in the Fragment):

```
for (java.util.Map ploc : arrayOfPins) {
    LatLng pCoord = ploc.get("Location");
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(pCoord)
            .title("Pin"));
}
```

The first error comes on the `java.util.Map ploc`:

> error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Map

Then, the other error is on `LatLng pCoord = ploc.get("Location")`.

Here is a picture of my Firestore Database:
[image: Database]

I thought that when you use `getData()` it returns the fields of the document as a Map.

So, why are the elements in `arrayOfPins` not `Maps`?

Comment: Firestore can only store JSON data (or Java classes that can be converted to/from JSON data) in its documents. But without seeing how you store the data, and what it looks like in the database, it's impossible to say much more.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for the response. Would it help if I added a picture of my Cloud Firestore database (from the firebase console)?

Comment: @TanayN Yes, it will be very very helpful. Please also respond with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo I made the changes. Hope it helps!

Comment: @TanayN Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that when you use getData() it returns the fields of the document as a Map.

Indeed, QueryDocumentSnapshot's [getData()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot#getData()) method returns a `Map<String, Object>` object. However, to get the data under `Location` property, you should explicitly call `.get("Location")` on the QueryDocumentSnapshot object, like in the following lines of code:

```
pinColRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>) document.get("Location");
                if (map != null) {
                    Log.d("TAG", map.get("latitude") + ", " + map.get("longitude"));

                    //Add the markers on the map
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```